# OpenCV(4.2.0) (-206:Bad flag (parameter or structure field)) Unrecognized or unsupported array type in function 'cvGetMat'

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

i am trying to inpaint on a 8000x4000 image, and a 8000x4000 binary mask but getting the following error.

> error                                     Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in 
>         1 img = cv.imread('input/200130_033344133.jpg')
>         2 mask = cv.imread('resources/maskX.png',0)
>   ----> 3 dst = cv.inpaint(img,mask,3,cv.INPAINT_TELEA)
>         4 cv.imshow('dst',dst)
>         5 cv.waitKey(0)
>
> error: OpenCV(4.2.0)
>   C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\core\src\array.cpp:2492:
>   error: (-206:Bad flag (parameter or structure field)) Unrecognized or
>   unsupported array type in function 'cvGetMat'

here is my code.
what i tried was to convert the image and the mask to numpy array or cv2.UMat. but all in vain

```
img = cv.imread('input/200130_033344133.jpg')
mask = cv.imread('resources/maskX.png',0)
dst = cv.inpaint(img,mask,3,cv.INPAINT_TELEA)
cv.imshow('dst',dst)
cv.waitKey(0)
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

any reason why its not working?
the images are loading properly i checked.

Answer (score 2):

I do not know what is wrong, because it works fine for me on Python 3.7 and OpenCV 3.4 on Mac OSX.

Did you import cv?  Is your mask more than 1 channel after making grayscale?  Perhaps it is an issue with OpenCV 4?

Here is what works for me.

Image with scratch:

[image]

Scratch Mask:

[image]

```
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('zelda1_scratch.jpg')
mask = cv2.imread('zelda1_scratch_mask.png',0)
dst = cv2.inpaint(img,mask,3,cv2.INPAINT_TELEA)
cv2.imwrite('zelda1_scratch_inpainted.jpg', dst)
cv2.imshow('dst',dst)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error while trying to inpaint.

```
error: (-206:Bad flag (parameter or structure field)) Unrecognized or unsupported array type in function 'cvGetMat'
```

Then I realised I typed the mask format incorrectly instead of `.jpg` I wrote `.png`. So `cv2.imread()` was loading an empty matrix. When I fixed typo, error was gone.

So please check again your input image and mask name and formats.

I think this error is the sign of that image cannot loaded correctly.

Sincerely,
Enes